# How to get game coordinates in the entire world?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to get the coordinates in the entire game. But when I call `Gdx.input.getX()` or `Gdx.input.getY()`, it only gives the screen coordinates and not the coordinates in the entire game.

I have tried this method:

```
private Vector3 mouse_position = new Vector3(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), 0);

mainCamera.unproject(mouse_position);
System.out.println(mouse_position.x + "  " + mouse_position.y);
```

... but this gives a totally false coordinates. I think I'm missing something here.

Both these methods are used in my `render()` method if that matters.

Comment: You set mouse position to the screen width and height instead of the actual mouse position. Use Gdx.input.getX() and getY() before unprojecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass current mouse position and then unproject it using camera.

```
Vector3 mouse_position = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);

mainCamera.unproject(mouse_position);
System.out.println(mouse_position.x + "  " + mouse_position.y);
```